# Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I'm attempting to use Net Core in my mvc application for security policies. Articles I've read said I need to install DependencyInjection which I'm doing through NuGet in VS 2017.  I'm getting the following error:

Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Is this version too new for .net 4.5.2?  What version should I be using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you check the dependencies you can see it depends on NetStandard 2.0. From [this chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) you can see that you must be using at .net 4.6.1 to be compatible with NetStandard 2.0.

If you use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 1.1.1 that is compatible .NETStandard 1.0 which is compatible with .NET 4.5 or newer.

Comment: I want cross-platform, .Net Core 2.0 and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 2.2.0 seem to accept one another.

Answer (score 7):

In the [package in nuget.com](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/) I can see the version 2.0 has a dependency with .Net Standard 2. .Net Standard 2 is compatible with .NET Framework 4.6.1. Also, you must install .Net Core 2 SDK to have .Net Standard 2 as supported platform in Visual Studio. Also, only Visual Studio 2017 Update 3 is supported. So you must use Visual Studio 2017 Update 3 with .Net Core 2 SDK and .Net Framework 4.6.1 as platfform for the project. The simplest option is installing version 1.1.1 of the package.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked for me and saved me from additional frustration.